# c#. How to open multiple local ports forwarding

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I'm trying to open multiple local ports but I don't know how I should do it.

At present I'm trying to read a CSV file with all local ip & ports and remote ip/ports.
This works fine but I'm not sure how to add multiple forwardedPortLocal. Does anyone give an example or tell me how I should do it?

Thanks

```
                    ForwardedPortLocal portStaticODBC = null;

var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "configSrv1.csv");
                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        if (!line.StartsWith("#"))
                        {
                            if (line.Contains(";"))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    string[] dnsPort = line.Split(',');

                                    string ipLocal    = dnsPort[0].ToString().Trim();
                                    uint portLocal  = uint.Parse(dnsPort[1].ToString().Trim());
                                    string ipRemote   = dnsPort[2].ToString().Trim();
                                    uint portRemote = uint.Parse(dnsPort[1].ToString().Trim());

                                    portStaticODBC = new ForwardedPortLocal(ipLocal, portLocal, ipRemote, portRemote);

                                    clientServer1.AddForwardedPort(portStaticODBC);
                                    portStaticODBC.Start(); //--> here?                                        
                                }
                                catch { }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    portStaticODBC.Start(); //--> here?
```

Answer (score -1):

Doing some test I think this is the solution.

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "configSrv1.csv");
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    if (!line.StartsWith("#"))
                    {
                        if (line.Contains(";"))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                string[] dnsPort = line.Split(',');

                                string ipLocal    = dnsPort[0].ToString().Trim();
                                uint portLocal  = uint.Parse(dnsPort[1].ToString().Trim());
                                string ipRemote   = dnsPort[2].ToString().Trim();
                                uint portRemote = uint.Parse(dnsPort[1].ToString().Trim());

                                portStaticODBC = new ForwardedPortLocal(ipLocal, portLocal, ipRemote, portRemote);

                                clientServer1.AddForwardedPort(portStaticODBC);
                                **portStaticODBC.Start(); //--> here?**                                        
                            }
                            catch { }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It would be nice, if you explain what did you actually change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).